# Failure to bare boot windows 7 that was installed under kvm

Tags: windows-7, kvm-virtualization, boot

I installed windows 7 (enterprise, amd64) in kvm (to /dev/hdb) because I don't have a dvd drive on this box, so I just started kvm with the parameters "-hda /dev/hdb -cdrom win7.iso".

That installs & boots just fine, however when I try to boot it without virtualization it gives me a blue screen but reboots before I can see what the error is.

I'm booting it like this:

```
title           win7-amd64
rootnoverify    (hd2,0)
map             (hd0) (hd2)
map             (hd2) (hd0)
makeactive
chainloader     +1
```

(hd2 is hdb)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a USB zip drive? You can copy an iso on to a USB pen and make it bootable using this utility: http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/en-GB/Help/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool.

I don't know if you're trying to have this install both virtualised and physical simultaneoulsy, so this is just a suggestion as to how to install without a CD Drive. I do know, however, that VMWare fusion in mac can virtualise it's bootcamp partition so that it can be run as both physical and virtual, however I think this may be something to do with the small Hardware Compatibility List that Apple has and that VMWare's virtual hardware is close enough to the actual spec of the machine that it doesn't notice the difference.

It could, however, be something as simple as kvm emulating IDE and then you try to boot from AHCI, as I know that causes blue-screens when switching between the two. Perhaps as a test try switching to IDE temporarily to see if it boots, if it does then try to create a VM with AHCI, or edit your current VM's registry and VM settings.

Comment: This could be it, my kvm install could simply not have the nvidia ide/sata drivers required to load the rest of the OS. I tried installing them in kvm, but it refused because the hardware isn't present. I'll see if I can find a large enough flash drive somewhere.

Comment: There is no SATA emulation with kvm, so I'll try VirtualBox, thanks for the helpful insight!